# Kendo DropDownListFor() with ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have a problem into the **ASP.NET-MVC Helper 
I have a form that give a POST into action **create** of the controller **Occurrence** passing a parameter of type **occurrence** that corresponding at the **Model** of the *view* where the **form** is inserted, for register the occurrence is needed an **TypeOccurrenceID**, i'm trying to get this value using **Html.DropDownListFor()**, but this not working when the form is posted, the **Occurrence** past in the parameter don't have 
the OccurrenceTypeId corresponding with the OccurrenceType selected in the DropDownList

Someone had the same problem?

**This is my Controller action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Occurrence occurrence)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Add<Occurrence>(occurrence);
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
            }
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
    }
```

**Here is my View**

```
@using Common.Util
@using Common.Util.Configuration
@using CafData
@model Occurrence

<div class="box-form">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Occurrence",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            OnSuccess = "OnSuccess()",
            OnFailure = "OnFailure()"
        }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@*Area*@

        <div class="row-fluid details-field">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("areas")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
              .OptionLabel("Selecione uma area...")
              .DataTextField("Description")
              .DataValueField("IdArea")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("readAreasForDropDown", "Area");
                  });
              })
        )


@*Occurrence type*@

          @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.OccurrenceTypeId)
              .Name("occurrencetype")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
              .OptionLabel("Select a occurrence type...")
              .DataTextField("Description")
              .DataValueField("OccurrenceTypeId")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("lerOccurrenceTypeForDropDown",                       
                      "OccurrenceType").Data("filterArea"). 
                      Type(HttpVerbs.Post);
                  })
                  .ServerFiltering(true);
              })
              .Enable(false)
              .AutoBind(false)
              .CascadeFrom("areas")
        )

        <script>
            function filterArea() {
                return {
                      id: $("#areas").val()
                 };
            }
        </script>

        <button class="k-button">Save</button>

    }

</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Sorry for the bad english!

Comment: solved, but I can only post the answer after 8 hours because of the reputation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was the name of the dropdownlist, it must be the same name as the property of the model that you want bind.

**Example:**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.OccurrenceTypeId)
          .Name("OccurrenceTypeId")
```

**Alternative:**

The name property is not actually necessary when using DropDownListFor. So just removing this line would work as well:

```
 .Name("occurrencetype")
```

Comment: I don't believe you need to specify the `Name` when using `DropDownListFor<>`

Comment: you're right, the real problem was the Name different of the property  specified in the DropDownListFor<>, if i had taken out the .Name probably would work.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote you a hundred times. You just saved me hours of work.

Comment: Although you don't need to specify the Name for the DropDownListFor<> to work, you may need to assign it a name or id if you want to access it with scripts using CSS selectors.

Comment: @LucasKonrath Thank you alot

Comment: @LucasKonrath you are right in saying the name must match with property it is bound to but not having a name is not an option if you have to do further action using the foreign key bound to dropdown. I wish I had stumbled on this post earlier. Thanks