# Kendo ui mvc dropdownlistfor with boolean type value using Entity Framework

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview, kendo-ui-mvc

```
 @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Is_Active)
 //instead of @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Is_Active)"
```

I am using entity crud operation and `Is_Active` is a boolean type value. On generating edit view it shows dropdown list which code is

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Is_Active)
```

and I want to change it in kendo ui using

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Is_Active)
```

but it shows blank dropdown list - please provide a response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813076/kendo-dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the DataSource for the DropDownList otherwise there is no list of items in it.  You use the .BindTo() for that.

Html.EditorFor() works because the internal implementation for a boolean creates the True/False item list for you.

When you explicitly define a DropDownList you need to provide both the value AND the list of potential values using .BindTo(), i.e.

```
@{
    var boolDataSource = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "True", Value = "True" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "False", Value = "False" }
    };
    // Or however/wherever you want to define the list of items that the DropDownList uses.
}


@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Is_Active).BindTo(boolDataSource)
```

Comment: Working Fine. Thanks :)